# continuous function defined on closed bounded interval is bounded? is the continuous necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

I've seen the proof about this theorem, but I am wondering if this condition **continuous** is necessary? My gut feels as long as a function is defined on a closed set, which means every element in the domain are defined, will not play around like the open set which can go to infinity. e.g $$f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}\\x\to \frac{1}{x}$$

appreciate any comments.

Comment: Note that the theorem in the title is false as stated: one needs the closed set itself to be bounded for the theorem to hold (otherwise $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some more things in heaven and earth than are dreamt of in our philosophy....

Once we start getting into the habit of thinking about functions that aren't continuous, we can find all kinds of less well-behaved examples. For example, define $f\colon [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
n, &\text{if } x = \frac1n \text{ for some positive integer }n, \\
1/(x-1), &\text{if } x\in [0,1]\setminus\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is defined on a closed interval yet is neither bounded above nor bounded below.

Answer (score 3):

1. $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$, $g(x)=\begin{cases}1/x&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ is unbounded on the compact set $[0,1]$.
2. $u:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$, $u(x)=x$ is unbounded and continuous on the closed set $[0,\infty)$.
3. $v:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $v(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\ 1&\text{if }x\notin \Bbb Q\end{cases}$ is bounded and discontinuous on ever subset of $\Bbb R$ (closed or otherwise) that contains an interval.